# eCheck if it's safe to move a directory and replace it with a symlink

Tags: directory, symlink, move

Say the directory you want to move has absolute path `DIR`. A case where it is NOT safe: that directory has either

- absolute path symlinks to within `DIR` itself. For instance `DIR/link` -> `/PATH/TO/DIR/file`. EDIT: as pointed out in a comment below, this should still be safe.
- relative path symlinks to outside `DIR`. For instance `DIR/link` -> `../../other_dir/file`.

Is there a tool that checks whether it's safe to move a directory and replace it with a symlink?

Comment: (1) should still be safe. If you make move `/DIR` to `/foo` and make a new `/DIR > /foo` symlink, any symlinks that point to `/DIR/bar` should resolve to `/foo/bar`. With (2) what matters is where you move `/DIR` to, whether or not you create a symlink that points to the new location is irrelevant.

Comment: Added some clarifications to my examples. I see now that (1) should still be safe.

Comment: In general, this is NOT SAFE. This is changing the structure of the directory  tree. Any application expecting to use this directory tree will malfunction